# The add() in function only add two elements to the list

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

Here this function is supposed to take care of entry of data in a Singly-Linked List, If there is no item in the list it adds it to the head and after that onwards, This **add()** function is called on a while loop till the user wants to continue. But this is only adding the first two data and is not working for the rest of the list

```
struct node{
int data;
struct node *nextptr;
}*head;

 int add()
    {
        struct node *ptr,*tmp;
        int value;
        ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if(ptr==NULL)
        {
            printf("MEMORY ALLOCATION FAILED ");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ENTER THE VALUE YOU WANT TO ENTER ");
            scanf("%d",&value);
            if(head==NULL)
            {
                ptr->data=value;
                ptr->nextptr=NULL;
                head=ptr;
            }
            else
            {   tmp=head;
                ptr->data=value;
                ptr->nextptr=NULL;
                tmp->nextptr=ptr;
                ptr=ptr->nextptr;
                tmp=tmp->nextptr;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Kindly try to tell the problem in this method, I have came across different ways to do the same but I just need to know why it can't be implemented this way.

Comment: _This add() function is called on a while loop till the user wants to continue._ dont do that , instead add the next elements in while loop

Comment: OKay, Give me a moment . I'm on to it. 

Edited     @IrAM It's not working.

Comment: The reason I told you that because, `tmp->nextptr=ptr;` always adds the new element at the end of head, you are not traversing till the last added element, so better to use `while` inside add, reach to NULL from `head` and add the new element when you reach `NULL`

Comment: Yes , I got that !

But Could you tell me a way to fix it with minimal changes @IrAM

Comment: check the answer below

Comment: Yea, Sure . Give me a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your else part should be like this

```
else {
    // asign head to tmp
    tmp = head;

    // traverse till you reach NULL
    while(tmp->nextptr)
        tmp = tmp->nextptr;

    // add new element when you reach NULL
    tmp->nextptr = ptr;
}
```